# How to redirect direct hits

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I have no idea what it would be called.

I have done a quick Google and search here on SO.

Perhaps it would be better asked, how do I redirect `http://site.com/shop` to a specified URL like `http://othersite.com/page` without it affecting `http://site.com/shop/?q=test` or any other $_GET's.

```
RewriteRule ^shop http://othersite.com/page [R=301,L]
```

Works fine apart from it also affects links like `http://site.com/shop/?q=test` which I want to work.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite to match against the query string (or to see if there is no query string):

```
RewriteEngine On
# blank query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
# check host
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^shop/?$ http://othersite.com/page [R=301,L]
```